# Laravel Seed with Relationship (Real Data)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-seeding

I'm trying to seed my table with some data with a belongsTo relationship, but I don't know how I should handle this relationship. Can anybody tell me what a belongsTo relationship should look like with seeding real data?

**Seed file**

```php
public function run()
{
    CarSchema::create([
        'type_of_car' => 'small',
        'horse_power' => 98,
        'brand'       => 3 // Want to get the brand of id 3 here
    ])
 }
```

The result I want is that "brand" is what corresponds to id 3 in the brand table so in the front End I've got the brand as well and not just the id of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Car model:

```php
public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Brand::class, 'brand_id');
}
```

Your Brand model:

```php
public function cars()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Car::class);
}
```

Your `cars` migration:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->enum('type_of_car', ['small', 'medium', 'large']); // just extra example
        $table->year('year');
        $table->mediumInteger('horse_power');

        // car's brand id below
        $table->unsignedInteger('brand_id');
        $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

---

To seed your `cars` table, you can insert any `id` from `brands` table into `brand_id` in your `cars` table, for example:

```php
Car::create([
    'name'        => 'S4',
    'type_of_car' => 'medium',
    'year'        => '2014',
    'horse_power' => 333,
    'brand_id'    => 3 // <-- this id should exist in brands table
]);
```

If you are seeding cars with random brands, you can insert a random brand id instead of hardcoding the id (like I did above with brand_id being 3):

```php
...
    'brand_id' => \App\Brand::all('id')->random()->id
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try :)

Comment: What if u had "brands" instead of "brand_id" as json, and in "brands" you had multiple "brand_id".  How should u connect the relationship then?

Comment: Don't think a car can have more than 1 brand?

Comment: And why are you storing it as json if you wanna reference it to a row in brands table? Do you know what you can do with relationships or are you new to it?

Comment: With the above, if you have a `name` field in your `brands` table, you can simply call `$car->brand->name` to get the car's brand name, its literally that easy and convenient.

Comment: Im pretty new to Laravel, Do u have slack or something, I can show u what I mean?

Comment: Sure, check my profile and contact me via anything @emotality

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187366/discussion-between-nahoj-and-emotality).